# How to get Graphic's object with out using a control in c# using GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I need to create a drawing with a circle and text embeded to it .This drawing is outputted as Image file (Jpeg/Jpg/svg/Png) using c# GDI+ .

Since i dont want to display the UI directly on a form ,how do i get the graphic's object to start drawing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at "Create from an Image Object" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did look into it before i posted the question,but some how it needed either a control or Image object as input.

Comment: Just use "Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200)" to create a new bitmap with width=200 and height=200

Comment: Please note: The `Graphics` object does not __contain__ any graphics; it is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new `Bitmap` passing the size for the image:

```
using (Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100)) {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap)) {
        // do your drawing here
    }

    myBitmap.Save(@"C:\path\for\image.bmp");
}
```

Optionally you can set the [`ImageFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx) for the image when saving

```
myBitmap.Save(@"C:\path\for\image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 3):

You create a Bitmap, and get the graphics object from it to draw on:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\MyImg.bmp");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
```

Note that the `Bitmap` does not *need* to be created on disk, it can be created in memory too!

Comment: bmp can be deleted after i create a new image out of it?

Comment: @GingerJack: sure, you can delete/rename bitmap file, or store it in memory.

Comment: @GingerJack my example created a Bitmap on disk, as says my update - it can be created entirely in memory too.